# Android app-heart beat

Tags: android

I am new to android and working on an android project where i need to constantly monitor heart beat rate(in running,walking,rest state) state.It will be a kind of back ground service.Being an IT student i don't have much idea how to make heart beat sensor and the heart beat apps which use flash light of android phone are not that accurate and a person needs to stand still.I need to make a heart beat sensor which can measure the heart beat of user without troubling the user.Shall i buy a digital heart beat sensor?Or is it possible to make it?Kindly help...Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible if you don't use additional hardware, which is closely attached to an artery. The built-in sensors are not sensitive enough to get the heartbeat precisely.

DIY: Use an old headphone and solder it to a microphone connector. Than put the speaker on your body like a stethoscope. The speaker will work like a microphone and should record the heartbeat. This signal can be processed by an android application. I tried this many years ago with an old cassette player, so it should work with modern phones anyway.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.But does the wristband work?i searched about the wrist bands and found that they are inaccurate.Best device till now is samsung galaxy s5 which has optical sensor.But i want to make an app which can measure the heart beat without troubling the person..means automatically ..